# Dynamically resize the height of FancyBox

Tags: jquery, dynamic, resize, height, fancybox

I'm looking to have the height of my Fancybox resize itself dynamically when I click the link 'Show Comments' which slides down a Disqus element.'

```
$(".video").fancybox({

    'transitionIn'      : 'none',
    'padding'       :'0',
    'transitionOut'     : 'none',
    'overlayColor'      : '#ebeeef',



});
```

That's what I'm using so far, I know that I can somehow use

```
    $.fancybox.resize();
```

But I'm not sure where to put it and how to link it so that when a div is clicked it will re-size.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say the "Show Comments" link that you would like to use to trigger the resize has the id `#showComments`.  Then you could add something like this after the JavaScript that you already have:

```
$("#showComments").click( function {
    $.fancybox.resize();
} );
```

This should resize the height of the Fancybox to match its content's height when the link is clicked.